# db2 how to give a user privilege/authorization to create variables

Tags: variables, db2, authorization, privileges

How do I give a user privilege/ authorization to create variables in a db2 database?

At the moment all I can find is documentation on how to grant permissions to a variable that already exists.

The user has an sql script they want to run which creates 3 variables but encountering an error saying they do not have the privilege or authorization to "CREATE VARIABLE".

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please clarify the DB2 platform and its version/release. Answers are likely to be different for different combinations.

Comment: ... why are you doing this?  What issue is the user trying to solve?  Normally I'd expect this to be handled by regular DBAs (who should already have appropriate permissions), especially as they'd be the ones responsible for them.  Can your DBAs not run the script as part of their regular tasks?